# Is there a way of entering ranges into my customised nmap db file?

Tags: tcp, udp, ports, nmap, sctp

I am trying to define my own port definitions in nmap and thus I am writing a customised version of nmap-services. The problem I have is that I cannot define a range of ports for a particular service i.e. a service on ports 1024-65355. I can't copy and paste because there are so many. I have looked around but cannot find anything about it.

This is within the /usr/share/nmap/nmap-services file. So i would like to define a service such as say telnet (example) which runs over ports 1024-65535. How would I go about writing this in the file. I have already tried the following:

```
telnet 1024.65535/tcp 0 #telnet
```

Comment: I can't help but think that you are trying to solve the wrong problem. What do you want to accomplish with this?

Comment: Some of the services offered by my hardware on some of the ports have nothing to do with the generic nmap gives. So I created a custom services db file with the correct service to port mappings. But a few services map more than one port, so i wasn't sure how to define a range of ports for a service.